# Understanding Mapping Methods in Java

Tags: java, mapping, adapter

I'm new to Java and would like some direction on how to understand the concept of mapping method returns of different classes. I am trying to use the Adapter pattern using the object way but in the method i want to use i'm not understanding mapping one classes method results into the method i want. I have a mehtod to return object of a class from an interface public theClass getThing(String thing) and want another classes method results, anotherClass getThing() to be used in the theClass method getThing(). I have tried to cast the results but saw that did nothing. i have looked up the Map<> way but not sure if its the solution.

Comment: provide examples of your code. would be easier for the audience to understand.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). 
From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." - Please add your code example.

Comment: Give some code samples with maybe some comments clarifying what do you want to do